# Disable automatic cast of cidr columns in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, cidr

When using rails4 and having columns in a postgresql database of type `cidr`, rails now casts them to type `IPAddr`. In rails 3 they we simple strings.

How can I disable this casting so that I get the values as simple strings, just as in rails 3?

Comment: It does not work as intended. Also validation does not really work, as you get an exception right away when assigning an invalid value to the attribute.

Comment: So the mutator method that AR creates is doing `IPAddr.new` when you assign a value and `IPAddr.new` is raising an `ArgumentError`, right?

Comment: Exactly. So my validations never run... :(

Comment: I'd call this a Rails bug, I can `m.some_int = 'pancakes'` and The Right Thing Happens without an exception so I'd think that `cidr` should behave the same. The string-to-IPAddr mangler inside AR should probably be wrapped in an exception handler so that you can have consistent behavior. You might be able to monkey patch some sense into it, grep the Rails source for `cidr` and hopefully you'll find somewhere for a narrow monkey patch.

Comment: Look inside [`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/cast.rb` for `string_to_cidr`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/cast.rb#L99) and you'll see the converter. You might note that the `json` type suffers from similar exception problems but that would rarely be a problem since JSON strings would usually be produced from `obj.to_json` calls.